# Cannot convert value of type 'NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier?' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: macos, storyboard, segue, swift4

Im using the following code to show a view controller,im identifying the segue using the identifier property.This code works fine in swift3 but when updating to swift4 I get the following error

***Cannot convert value of type 'NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier?' to expected argument type 'String'***

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segue") {
        //get a reference to the destination view controller
        let destinationVC:ProgressView = segue.destinationController as! ProgressView

        //set properties on the destination view controller
        destinationVC.fileArray=fileArray
        destinationVC.croptype=croptype
        destinationVC.outdir=outdir
        destinationVC.fileformat=fileformat
        destinationVC.tflag=tflag
        if(resize==true)
        {
        destinationVC.resize=true
        destinationVC.rwidth=rwidth
        destinationVC.rheight=rheight
        destinationVC.preserve_aspect_ratio=preserve_aspect_ratio
        }

    }
}
```

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 4 the type of the segue identifier has been changed to `NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier`

Two solutions

1. Compare the `rawValue` – and safely unwrap the identifier

   ```
   if let identifier = segue.identifier, identifier.rawValue == "segue" { ...
   ```
2. (recommended) Create an extension

   ```
   extension NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier {
       static let segue = NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier("segue")
   }
   ```

   and compare

   ```
   if let identifier = segue.identifier, identifier == .segue { ...
   ```